# Possible to back up a VPN connection in Windows 10/11?

Tags: windows

I have a VPN connection I would like to "save". In Windows 10.

Is this possible, so that when I do a reinstall, I can easily just recreate this vpn connection?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just tried making a VPN connection to test this.

Try pasting this into an address bar:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\
```

You should see a file called `rasphone.pbk` (or a folder called `_hiddenPbk` with that file inside. This should contain your VPN connection(s). Double-click on it to check.

If it is, you can just copy that file/folder to any other computer or user account by using the same folder address.

Comment: And, for those curious, this works just fine for Windows 8 as well.

Comment: **A comment from another user:**  I had a folder called `hidden_pbk` (though the folder is not hidden) with another `rasphone.pbk`. I have 6 VPN's setup but they appeared to all be contained in one file.

Answer (score 11):

If the connection is setup for all users, you'll find it in

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
```

Hope this helps